# Sending commands to the terminal from a script

Tags: perl

How do you send commands to the terminal in a perl script?

For example, if I want to run the command `mkdir $directory` in the console, what do I type in the perl script?

Comment: http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands I believe should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modeling off the sample code in the documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html:

```
@args = ("mkdir", $directory);
system(@args) == 0
    or die "mkdir failed";
```

Perl can make directories without `system()` calls, but I assume you want to do other things and are just using mkdir as an example.

Comment: Can also use backticks `` around the command to capture the output, if you need it (eg  $i=`cat foo.txt` puts the contents of foo.txt into $i)

Comment: @Nialscorva: Or `$i = qx{cat foo.txt}` if you need to get around Markdown.

Answer (score 5):

For executing any system command from perl script you need use system command with a backtick

For e.g

In your case for creating a directory you need to type

system(`mkdir $directory`); #note html is not showing the backtick but backtick is place before mkdir and after $directory

It will create a dir in current working dir in the name of $directory

Answer (score 4):

Since Perl has the `mkdir()` system call built in, you don't need to use the `system` command at all:

```
my $directory = "...";
if (mkdir $directory)
{
    croak "Failed to create directory $directory ($!)";
}
```

If you must use `system`, do so the safe way:

```
if (system "mkdir", $directory)
{
    croak "Failed to create directory $directory";
}
```

This form of the `system` statement (with a list of arguments) avoids the problems of shell expansion.

Comment: There's also the File::Path package, which will make or remove more than one level at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use perl commands instead of relying on shell commands. There are a great many things that perl can do, and if it is not already [built in](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html), or a [core module](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-F.html), it's likely available on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

As people have mentioned, [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) is available, and so are most of the [basic file related commands](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions-by-cat.html#Functions-for-filehandles,-files,-or-directories).

That being said, here's the dirt on shell commands in perl:

You want the perl script to:

- Wait while the shell command is performed and check its exit status.
  Use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)
- Wait and capture the *standard output* of the shell command. Use [`qx//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html), or
  backticks.
- Abandon perl script to run another command. Use
  [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html). But usually, you'll not really want to use `exec`, for
  reasons described in the link above.
- Run the system command and pipe input or output to/from it. Use
  [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) with MODE either `-|` or `|-`, respectively.

Comment: It should be stressed that `exec` does not return to the calling program, i.e. the perl process running the perl code is replaced by the `exec`'ed program. This means that code following the call to `exec` is never executed, unless `exec` fails to invoke the program.

Comment: @danielkullmann Good point. I've never really used `exec`, beyond learning never to use it, some 10-15 years ago. =)